# Ionic 3 + laravel. Problema com requisição http no servidor

Tags: laravel, ionic, post, http-request

Edit: Solução
O 000webhost não aceita requisições '`options`' no seu plano gratuito. consegui resolver o problema fazendo o laravel ficar disponível em rede local com a função `php artisan serve --host=IP --port=8000`

---

Estou desenvolvendo um app híbrido com Ionic 3 e Laravel como Back-end.
Tive que hospedar o back-end em um servidor online(000webhost) para fazer alguns testes no aplicativo, foi nessa hora que começou meus problemas.
Antes de hospedar, usando meu computador como servidor (localhost), conseguia fazer qualquer tipo de requisição através de providers no Ionic.
Usando a hospedagem do webhost, só consigo fazer requisições GET, qualquer outro tipo de requisição da o erro `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. Tentando fazer o mesmo tipo de requisição utilizando o postman ela é processada com sucesso.

Meu arquivo de configuração  cors.php está da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laravel CORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
    | to accept any value.
    |
    */

    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,

];
```

A rota que eu estou tentando acessar:

```
Route::post ('ajudado/', 'AjudadoController@set_ajudado');
```

E o método do provider que faz a requisição no ionic:

```
set_ajudado(dados):Promise<any>
  {
    return this.http.post(this.url, dados).toPromise().then(function(data){
      return  data; 
   });
  }
```

Comment: Você desabilitou a validação do token?

Comment: Sim, mas já descobri o problema...
O 000webhost não aceita requisições 'options' no seu plano gratuito.
consegui resolver o problema fazendo o laravel ficar disponível em rede local. Mesmo assim, obrigado pela ajuda!